# Deploy Laravel Upgrade - Composer Update or Composer Install

Tags: git, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.6

My production App is build on Laravel 5.3. Since Laravel 5.6 is out, I have been upgrading my Laravel. This is what I have done so far in my Development server:

1. Went through each upgrade changes in Laravel site and using Git comparison tool, I added the code changes from 5.3 < 5.4 < 5.5 < 5.6.
2. Edited my App codes to reflect the changes.
3. Run `composer update`.
4. Commit all the changes to Git repo.

So far so good since it is a development machine. Usually when I push any updates to the production server, I only do `git pull origin master` and thats it. Since this is my first upgrade of Laravel done after its release, my concern in, after I push the new updates to production server, do I run: `composer update` or `composer install` in my production server?

I have read many posts advising to use `composer install` in production server in general and I usually do that when I add new packages to my Laravel. However in this case, since it is infact an upgrade of all core files along with updates to existing packages, do I still run `composer install` or should I be doing `composer update` in this case? When I push commits, it also commits the composer.lock file from dev site.

Can someone please clarify this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should allways do `composer install` in production along with `composer.lock` file.

if you do composer update then it may break your application because it is possible that dependency of the packages may have changed.

in production also make sure you put your composer.lock file too. `composer install` will only install the versions which are in your composer.lock file, so you will have the same code in production and development.

You can read more about

https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#lock-file

Comment: Thank you for confirming that. What I wonder is, when I currently have Laravel 5.3 files and then the composer.lock file shows laravel 5.6 and the new versions for already installed third party packages, does `composer install` remove the old package version and files and only install the new ones?

Comment: @Neel yess you are right, It will install the new one, but you can keep composer.lock file in commit history

Comment: fantastic. that helps me. Gives me the confidence to proceed with the deployment of these changes. Thank you so much @laravel levaral